# How can I change each number's background color?

Tags: vue.js

I am dealing with a simple project but have a problem:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const isActive = ref(false);
const rates = ref([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

const selectPick = () => {
  isActive.value = !isActive.value;
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-show="!isVisible" class="card-container">
      <div class="content-container">
      ...
        <ul>
          <li
            v-for="rate in rates"
            :key="rate"
            @click="selectPick"
            class="rating"
            :class="{ active: isActive }"
          >
            {{ rate }}
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

- My goal: When I click any number related button's background color should change to orange but if I click another, it must return the old paint.
- Problem: When I click any number all number's background color return orange.

[image]

Comment: define `ref` variable and change it value on `@click` event, setting clicked btn value. Then compare btn value with variable for custom styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define ref variable and change it value on @click event, setting clicked btn value. Then compare btn value with variable for custom styling.

Try this.

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-show="!isVisible" class="card-container">
      <div class="content-container">
      ...
        <ul>
          <li
            v-for="rate in rates"
            :key="rate"
            @click="activeRef = rate"
            class="rating"
            :class="{ active: activeRef === rate }"
          >
            {{ rate }}
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const activeRef = ref(null);
const rates = ref([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
</script>
```

Main changes in:

```
const activeRef = ref(null);
```

And

```
@click="activeRef = rate"
...
:class="{ active: activeRef === rate }"
```